# How to make Jetpack Compose theme customizable?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, themes, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a Design System with Jetpack Compose, I have a lot of components all using my theme to access the colors, typography and dimensions. Now I'm looking into the possibility of allowing customization. For instance, overriding a color resulting in this to change for every component.

What I've attempted so far adding parameters to fun MyTheme, I have had some success with this approach, but the problem is that any dev could modify the theme at any time like this. I would like for it to be customizable only once, maybe like a singleton. Any ideas or recommendations?

Here is my theme:

```
private val LightColorPalette = LightColors()
private val DarkColorPalette = DarkColors()

private val LocalColors = compositionLocalOf<MyColors> {
    error("No typography provided! Make sure to wrap all usages of this components in a MyTheme.")
}

private val LocalTypography = compositionLocalOf<MyTypography> {
    error("No typography provided! Make sure to wrap all usages of this components in a MyTheme.")
}

private val LocalDimensions = staticCompositionLocalOf { MyDimensions() }

@Composable
fun MyTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    colors: MyColors = if (darkTheme) DarkColorPalette else LightColorPalette,
    typography: MyTypography = getTypography(LocalConfiguration.current),
    dimensions: MyDimensions = getDimensions(LocalConfiguration.current),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val shapes = MaterialShapes

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalTypography provides typography,
        LocalColors provides colors,
        LocalDimensions provides dimensions,
    ) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colors = debugColors(darkTheme),
            content = content,
            shapes = shapes
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the following documentation [page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/custom) talks about exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by making all my **CompositionLocal** variables public. With this, any new theme that overrides this variables with **CompositionLocalProvider** will have the composables under it using this new values.

```
@Composable
fun SecondaryTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

    val colors = SecondaryColors()
    val typography = getDefaultTypography(configuration)
    val dimensions = getDefaultDimensions(configuration)
    val shapes = MaterialShapes

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalTypography provides typography,
        LocalColors provides colors,
        LocalDimensions provides dimensions,
    ) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colors = materialColors(darkTheme),
            content = content,
            shapes = shapes
        )
    }
}
```

I recommend checking the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal)